# Error with php version when trying to install laravel with composer

Tags: php, macos, laravel, terminal, composer-php

So, it's been two days now and I have been struggling with installing laravel on my old mac 10.6
My computer runs PHP 5.5.27

But for some reason when i use this code in the terminal:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name ~4.2.0 --prefer-dist`

I get this:

`- laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.8 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.7 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.6 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.5 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.4 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.3 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.2 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.17 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.16 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.15 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.14 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.13 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.12 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.11 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.10 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v4.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (5.3.26) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].`

`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

Anyone has any idea as to why laravel doesn't recognize my version of php?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there are several PHP are installed on your machine.
Use the following shell command to check the first php in your PATH environment.

> which php

Comment: Ok, so i wrote php -i in the terminal and i got `phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.3.26` But when i do phpinfo(); in one of my .php files, on the browser it shows up as 5.5.27.. I don't understand

Comment: Check your nginx or apache configuration to confirm which php-fpm you are using. Besides, use ps to check which php-fpm is running.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i do that? I'm not too familiar with the terminal commands.